# Solve : $dy + [x\sin(2y)-x^3\cos^2y]dx = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I came across this question in one of my previous year papers. I am not understanding how to solve this or by using which method do I have to solve this question can someone please help me out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$dy + [x\sin(2y)-x^3\cos^2y]dx = 0$$
Substitute $u=x^2$
$$dy +\frac 12 [\sin(2y)-u\cos^2y]du = 0$$
Divide by ${\cos^2 y}$
$$\frac {dy}{\cos^2y} + [\tan(y)]du-\frac u 2du = 0$$
Note that the derivative of $\tan x$ is $\frac 1 {\cos^2 x}$

$$ {d \tan(y)}+ \tan(y)du-\frac u 2du = 0$$
$$ \frac {d \tan(y)} {du}+ \tan(y)=\frac u 2$$
$$w'+w=\frac u 2$$
That's a first order DE. Use any method you know to integer the DE.
$$\tan y =\frac 12 (u-1+Ke^{-u})$$
$$\tan y =\frac 12 (x^2-1+Ke^{-x^2})$$
$$y(x) =\arctan \{ {\frac 12 (x^2-1+Ke^{-x^2})}\}$$

---

Or rewrite it more simply $${d \tan(y)}+ \tan(y)du-\frac u 2du = 0$$ $${d( e^u\tan(y)})=\frac u 2e^udu $$ Integrate

Comment: Thanks @Isham ... But out of curiosity can we solve this problem using reducible to exact differential equation method?

Comment: Yes it' can be solved with exactness @Rakesh  Like here ${d( e^u\tan(y)})=\frac u 2e^udu$

Comment: $$d(\tan(y))+(\tan(y)−\frac u2)du=0$$ becomes exact with $e^u$ as integrating factor...@Rakesh

Comment: And for the original equation I think the integrating factor :$\mu(x,y)=e^{x^2}/cos^2(y)$ will make the differential exact. Check it.